# Sleep using "await Task.Delay"

Tags: c#, webclient

Well i want to wait for the WebClient to be free so i created a small code that waits until the WebClient's IsBusy property is false

Code :

```
public class WebAgent : WebClient
{
    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string uri, bool useDelay)
    {
        if (IsBusy) await WaitForFreedom();
        return await DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
    }

    public async Task WaitForFreedom()
    {
        while (IsBusy)
            await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

So i want to know is this a good way to achieve that or there is a better way to await the webclient freedom so i don't get the concurrent error ?

Comment: The easy solution is probably to not scope your `WebClient` at such a high level and try to reuse it so often.  Instead create a new one for each request so that you don't need to worry about concurrency issues between them.  It's not like it's a particularly expensive object to create.

Comment: No sorry i have to use 1 Webclient to hold up my cookies and simulate a real browser.

Comment: Use `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: and what is the difference regarding my question ?